# Autowiring in Spring WS causing null pointer

Tags: spring, web-services, soap, cxf

It's been a long time since I've worked with Spring, and my first time setting up Spring on a web service from scratch so...I may be asking some stupid questions here.

My service and all its beans are built with CXF. The relevant parts of the implementor look like this:

```
...

@WebService(
            endpointInterface = "mil.army.sddc.ibs.ccr.datamgmt.DataMgmtPortType",
            name="DataMgmt_Service",
            portName="DataMgmt_Port",
            targetNamespace = "http://ccr.ibs.sddc.army.mil/DataMgmt")
@Service("dataMgmtWebService")
public class DataMgmtWebServiceImpl implements DataMgmtPortType {

    @Autowired
    private RSNCodeDAO rsnCodeDAO;

    ...
```

That DAO, which looks like this

```
@Repository
public class RSNCodeDAO {
...
```

is in the applicationcontext.xml thusly:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context

   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
   http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws
   http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd">

   <context:component-scan base-package="https"/>
   <context:annotation-config />

   <context:component-scan base-package="mil.army.sddc.ibs.ccr.dbwrapper.dao" />

   <bean id="impl" class="mil.army.sddc.ibs.ccr.datamgmt.webservice.DataMgmtWebServiceImpl"/>

   <bean  id="reasonCodeDAO"
   class="mil.army.sddc.ibs.ccr.dbwrapper.dao.RSNCodeDAO" autowire="byName" />

   <jaxws:endpoint
        id="dataMgmtWebService"
        implementor="#impl"
        address="/DataMgmt" />
```

And lastly, I'm not sure if you need it, but here's the web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">

    <display-name>CCRDataMgmt</display-name>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

</web-app>
```

So if one of y'all knows what dumb thing I'm forgetting I'd appreciate it.

Edit: stack trace has been requested. I don't have logging set up yet, so apologies for the soap exception response format.

[Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/FqDWDdtR)

Comment: You didn't include the most important bit: the actual exception stack trace.

Comment: It's a null pointer exception where the DAO is called. I can't imagine what you'd learn from it, but I'm adding it just in case.

Comment: Why you define your beans expicitly (e.g. `<bean id="impl" ...>`, `<bean  id="reasonCodeDAO" ...>`) but *also* enable component scanning and annotation config? (i.e. use `@Service`, `@Repository`, etc.). Not sure if this could be the source of your problems but symptoms are consistent with `DataMgmtWebServiceImpl` not being managed by (i.e. visible to) Spring. You should try increasing Spring's internal logging level and inspect the startup log.

Comment: I doubled up just in case it would help. Originally it was just the bean declaration tag, then I added the component scan tag. It was an act of desperation.

I am researching Spring logging now, but I've just been told that this is no longer a priority so I don't know when I'll be able to get back to you with the results.

Answer (score 0):

In my environment

- jboss 6.4
- spring boot 1.4.3.RELEASE
- java 8

Extend *SpringBeanAutowiringSupport* did not work, or call SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(this) in the @PostConstruct either.
Jboss calls Apache cxf it creates the web service before creating the Spring context, to solve inject javax.xml.ws.WebServiceContext with javax.annotation.Resource, the same one that maintains information regarding the request. I copy the code:

```
@WebService(serviceName = "LibretasBcbWsImplService")
public class LibretasBcbWsImpl {
private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LibretasBcbWsImpl.class);

@Autowired
private AppProperties appProperties;

@Resource
WebServiceContext wsContext;

public LibretasBcbWsImpl() {
    log.info("Creando LibretasBcbWsImpl .............");
}

@PostConstruct
@WebMethod(exclude = true)
public void init() {
    log.info("wsContextwsContext es nulo? " + (wsContext == null)); //  Returns false when calling from client
    log.info("appProperties es nulo? " + (appProperties == null)); //   true when calling from client
    if (wsContext != null) {
        MessageContext mc = wsContext.getMessageContext();
        if (mc != null){
            ServletContext servletContext = (ServletContext) mc.get(MessageContext.SERVLET_CONTEXT);
            SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnServletContext(this, servletContext); 
        }
    }
    log.info("appProperties es nulo? " + (appProperties == null)); // return false!!!!! 
}

@WebMethod(operationName = "getLibsByIdLibreta")
@WebResult(name = "datos")
public Datos getLibsByIdLibreta(String id_libreta) {
    ...
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of `

```
<context:component-scan base-package="https"/>`
<context:component-scan base-package="mil.army.sddc.ibs.ccr.dbwrapper.dao" />
```

`

Try using `<context:component-scan base-package="https, mil.army.sddc.ibs.ccr.dbwrapper.dao"/>`

I am assuming that `DataMgmtWebServiceImpl` class of yours is residing under "https" package.

Comment: Both approaches are equivalent.

Comment: This was an example applicationcontext.xml that my boss gave me. I assumed originally that the line making https a base package was something necessary in general, but I guess it's just a package in the project he pulled it from. DataMgmtWebServiceImpl, as noted in its bean declaration, is in mil.army.sddc.ibs.ccr.datamgmt.webservice.